# Mountain bike or street

Tags: mountain-bike, handlebars

Can a mountain bike have 10 speed handelbars? Going back to look at it.  havent asked how many gears it has yet or the make.

Comment: Chances are you're asking the wrong questions. Look for a decent quality bike that fits well; the number of speeds is not particularly important (just need to have a low and high enough gear for the type of riding you do, and enough combinations between them to be comfortable). Do not buy a [tag:bso] (you often see these bikes around the neigbhorhood with "21 speed" or "18 speed" or similar in big letters); BSO's are crap.

Comment: By "10 speed handlebars" do you mean drop-bars like    https://www.ternbicycles.com/sites/default/files/images/gear/2016/05/tn-kinetix-pro-x-drop-bar-01_0.jpg ?   Please use the Edit link to expand your question with more info.

Comment: "going back to look at it"   are you asking for opinions on a bike you don't yet own?

Answer (score 2):

Depends on what you mean by 10 speed. In the 70s, there were many bikes on the market that had 2 chainrings (gears in front) and 5 cogs (gears in back), so had 10 gear combinations or speeds.

In many cases now, when someone encounters the term speeds they mean the number of cogs. These days, there are a decent number of bikes with 10 cogs in the back.

Nobody's stopping you from putting more than 10 cogs in the rear on a bicycle.

The current [Shimano XTR M9000 drivetrain](http://bike.shimano.com/content/sac-bike/en/home/components11/mountain/xtr-m9000.html) for mountain bikes lets you run a 3 x 11 (3 chainrings in the front, 11 cogs in the back). So, this is a 33 speed bike (in the old parlance).

Is having all these gearing combinations going to make your life better in any way? Maybe, maybe not. Unless you're [trying to be absurd,](https://www.sheldonbrown.com/org/otb.html) like this 63-speed bike by Sheldon Brown.

Answer (score 0):

As Criggie notes in the comments, you might be referring to a road bike with 2 chainrings and 5 cogs in the back like this:

[image]

(Picture in Public Domain)

There are a few mountain bikes which use drop handlebars (like the ones in the picture above) rather than flat handlebars in the picture below, but they're pretty rare these days. An example is the Salsa Fargo. Almost all bikes with drop handle bars are road bikes or cyclocross bikes.

Flat handlebars:
[image]

(Picture from [Decathlon](https://www.decathlon.co.uk/))

The Salsa Fargo:
[image]

(Picture from [Salsa Cycles](http://salsacycles.com/))